# How to Connect to a Server with No Modern SSL Ciphers

Tags: ssl, https

I recently acquired an old SonicWall firewall/VPN endpoint and would like to be able to access it. Unfortunately, it doesn't connect over HTTP and insists on HTTPS. Every browser I've tried no longer supports connecting to a system with such an old set of ciphers:

```
$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 8000 ip.add.re.ss

Starting Nmap 7.31 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-20 09:21 EST
Nmap scan report for ip.add.re.ss
Host is up (0.0061s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8000/tcp open  http-alt
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   SSLv3:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|_  least strength: C

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.19 seconds
```

Is there any way besides finding an old version of Firefox to install that will allow me to connect to this?

Comment: Not a direct solution but you could put a haproxy in front of it that'll present something acceptable to your browser, and broker SSL with the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open a new FireFox tab
2. Type: `about:config`
3. Accept the warning
4. Search in the search bar for the following values and change them as follows:

   - Search for `security.tls`
   - Change `security.tls.version.min` to `0`
   - Change `security.tls.version.fallback-limit` to `0`
   - Change `security.tls.unrestricted_rc4_fallback` to `true`

https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-54813